# How do I handle non-null in Typescript when I don't request the item via GraphQL? - Typescript - GraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I have a GraphQL (GQL) server and am using TypeScript (TS) on the front end. Here is my GQL type.

```
type AutomatedAlgorithmValue {
  politicalEntityAlgorithmValueId: Long
  politicalEntityId: Long!
  ...
}
```

`politicalEntityId` is non-nullable. This gives me the behavior if I ask for `politicalEntityId`, then it is guaranteed to be there, but if I don't ask for it then the query runs as normal.

I use [graphql-codegenerator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator) to create the TS types out of the GQL schema. The TS types makes the `politicalEntityId` as non-null, so now on the front end I have to always request the `politicalEntityId` as part of the `AutomatedAlgorithmValue` type even if it isn't something that I want to request.

In my front end code, I am holding the data in a hook

```
let [results, setResults] = useState<AutomatedAlgorithmValue[]>([]);
```

Here is my GQL request

```
executeAutomatedAlgorithmProcess(politicalEntityId: $id, type: $type) {
    values {
      politicalEntityAlgorithmValueId
    }
  }
```

At this point I don't need the `politicalEntityId`, but when I try to add the data to my `results`, the TS compiler knows I am adding `null` for the `non-null` property `politicalEntityId`  and an error is thrown.

It gets even worse if there is a `non-null` object with other `non-null` properties, because now the request gets larger and larger with each unnecessary `non-null` property/object.

How are others handling this? Do I have to create a new type each time? Do I use `Pick` to determine what the data is going to be in the `results` `hook`? Is there a plugin that makes everything nullable and if so should I use that?

Comment: just don't **duplicate data** from query into state? it's simply not necessary ... use alias to rename result `data`?

Comment: It isn't necessary, but then I lose all the type goodness when I use the result, or I have to create new types every time I pull some data out of a GQL query, which is just untenable.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you're using a type that is generated based off your GraphQL schema using graphql-code-generator's `typescript` plugin. As you are saying, these types have every field specified in the schema.

I believe what you also need to do is use the [typescript-operations plugin](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-operations). The typescript operations plugin basically does what you're talking about using `Pick`, but does it automatically based on the frontend queries you have defined. So the types that the typescript operations plugin generates match the operations you declare.

You'll also oftentimes use a third plugin on top of these two as well that is specific for you client like [react-query](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-query), [react-apollo](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo), [urql](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-urql), etc so you end up with ready to use hooks for each operation that have type safety.